Seeking in m3u8 streaming with VLKit
this is my first time using VLCKit.
I'm doing a few tests to see if I got the gist of integrating it into a SwiftUI app, everything was working smoothly until I stumbled in an issue that for the life of me I cannot fix.
I've done a number of tests with a number of video format, but I've found 2 m3u8 sources that I simply cannot properly play, of better yet I cannot seek.
The two sources are:

https://bradmax.com/static/video/tos/440272.m3u8
https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8

They are just demo sources that I found around just to test my code.
I've created the simplest possible code to reproduce the issue, here it goes.
import SwiftUI
import VLCKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = VideoPlayerViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VideoPlayerView(player: viewModel.player)
                .frame(width: 400, height: 300) // Set your desired frame
                .onAppear {
                    viewModel.setupPlayer()
                }
            Slider(value: $viewModel.seekTime, in: 0...viewModel.videoLength, onEditingChanged: { editing in
                viewModel.seekVideo(to: viewModel.seekTime)
            })
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

class VideoPlayerViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var player = VLCMediaPlayer()
    @Published var seekTime: Float = 0
    var videoLength: Float {
        return (player.media?.length.value?.floatValue ?? 0) / 1000
    }

    func setupPlayer() {
        let media = VLCMedia(url: URL(string: "https://bradmax.com/static/video/tos/440272.m3u8")!)
        player.media = media
        player.play()
    }

    func seekVideo(to time: Float) {
        let vlcTime = VLCTime(number: NSNumber(value: time * 1000))
        player.time = vlcTime
    }
}

struct VideoPlayerView: NSViewRepresentable {
    let player: VLCMediaPlayer

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        let view = NSView()
        player.drawable = view
        return view
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {
        // Update the view if needed.
    }
}

When I try to move the slider around to change position in the video stream, it doesn't change the position and it starts playing back from where it was.
Sometimes it does change position, but not to where I move the slider, it's all very strange.
I've tested the video stream with VLC 3.0.20 for macOS and I can successfully move around the timeline, which makes me thinking I'm doing something wrong in my code.
I'm using VLCKit 3.5.0.
Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Can you try with VLCKit 3.6.0b11?

Thanks for the suggestions. With VLCKit 3.6.0b11 it seems to work better. There is still an issue the very first time that I move the slider, which restarts the video, but the second time it does work and moves the time in the right position. The overall experience is still a little unstable tough, especially with the second stream. After successfully moving the slider, the video sometimes doesn't show while the audio works.

We need debug logs to find out what is happening precisely when you are seeking. Video recovering slowly after a seek with the audio being immediate might in fact be the expected behavior of HLS streams.

I guess that makes sense, but still sometimes the very first time I seek the video restarts. I can provide some logs if you are interesting in checking that out. I can use the VLCConsoleLogger to get it.
